# automatically run a series of unix and jmp scripts

Tags: shell, unix, sas-jmp

I need to run a cshell script on a file and then run a JMP-SAS script on the output file and at last run another cshell script on the output file. Does anyone know a way to this automatically?

Comment: Is it about the same output file? Both times? Or it's different files?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "automatically"?  Why can't you just run them by, you know, running them?

Comment: @AlexButenko each script runs with the output file of the previous script

Comment: @jwodder I meant running the whole series in one command. I want to run the first unix script and once I have the output file I want to run the JMP script with it and then the last unix script to run on the last output file instantly, without having to run each script by it's own everytime